# Error Update package ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, webserver, error-handling

Hello i have this error when launch apt-get update command on my ubuntu server :
how can i solve this?

```
    W: Impossibile scaricare alcuni file di indice: saranno ignorati o verranno usati quelli vecchi.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_14.10/  Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.opensuse.org_repositories_isv:_ownCloud:_community_xUbuntu%5f14.10_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_14.04/  Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.opensuse.org_repositories_isv:_ownCloud:_community_xUbuntu%5f14.04_Packages)
```

Answer (score 0):

> W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://....

You have a duplicate entry in your `source.list`

**Manually** :

Edit your `sources.list` , comment out or remove the duplicate entry.

**Through GUI** :

Install [**Y PPA Manager**](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/y-ppa-manager-updated-with-important.html)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Then choose **scan and remove duplicate PPAs** from the **advanced** options of **Y PPA Manager**